# Dart: Is is possible to make a factory method polymorphic?

Tags: inheritance, dart, polymorphism

Yes it's related to JSON deserialization.
I have a class `JsonStringSerializable`

```dart-lang
abstract class JsonStringSerializable {
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
}
```

Which I can extend

```dart-lang
class Cat extends JsonStringSerializable {

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => null;

  factory Cat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => null;
}
```

So now I can use any instance of `JsonStringSerializable` and expect the implementation of `toJson`.

My question is how can I do the same with `fromJson`? Is it possible in **Dart**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

A factory constructor, generative constructor or static method is not part of any *interface*. That means that you cannot abstract over them using a type. There is no *type* for "something which has a `toJson(Map<String,dynamic>)` constructor or static method".

The one thing you can do is to abstract over the function itself.

```dart
T createFromJson<T>(T fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json), Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  fromJson(json);
```

Then you can call that function with a function calling the constructor (or if you used a static method instead, directly with the tear-off of that method):

```dart
  createFromJson((map) => Cat.fromJson(map), json);
```